# Invalid SQL Query

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, exists, mysql-error-1054

I have the next query that in my opinion is a valid one, but I keep getting error telling me that there is a proble on "WHERE em.p4 = ue.p3" - **Unknown column 'ue.p3' in 'where clause'**.

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ue.p3
FROM 
    table1 AS ue INNER JOIN table2 AS e 
    ON ue.p3 = e.p3 
    WHERE 
        EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM (
                SELECT (COUNT(*) >= 1) AS MinMutual 
                FROM table4 AS smm 
                WHERE 
                    smm.p1 IN (
                        SELECT sem.p3 FROM table3 AS sem 
                        INNER JOIN table2 AS em ON sem.p3 = em.p3 
                        WHERE em.p4 = ue.p3 AND 
                        sem.type = 'friends' AND em.p2 = 'normal' ) AND 
                    smm.p5 IN (
                        15000,15151
                    )
            ) AS Mutual WHERE 
        Mutual.MinMutual = TRUE) LIMIT 11
```

If I execute the sub-query which is inside the EXISTS function, everything is O.K.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: does column `p3` exist in table1?

Comment: or rather: does column p3 exist in table3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you can only reference ***one*** subquery layer down when correlating.  Look at where the `ue` alias is defined, and count the number of FROM clauses until to you reach the next reference.

I re-wrote your query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ue.p3
  FROM table1 AS ue 
  JOIN table2 AS e ON ue.p3 = e.p3 
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 AS MinMutual 
                FROM table4 AS smm 
                JOIN TABLE3 sem ON sem.p3 = smm.p1
                               AND sem.type = 'friends'
                JOIN TABLE2 em ON em.p3 = sem.p3
                              AND em.p3 = ue.p3
                              AND em.p2 = 'normal'
               WHERE smm.p5 IN (15000,15151)
            GROUP BY ? --needs a group by clause, in order to use HAVING
              HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1)  
 LIMIT 11
```

EXISTS returns true if satisfied -- it doesn't evaluate based on the subquery returning "true".  There's no need for the additional subquery you have (which was causing problems anyway).

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the query as you suggested and that's worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this kind of correlated query is not doable in mysql as of now.  Join to a derived table as opposed to using the exists.